# SPARQL Query DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

i want to extract all movies from DBpedia with this query:

```
select * where {
?film  rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>
?film dbpprop:title ?acteurs
}
```

but i have this error:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 5: syntax error at '?film' before 'dbpprop:title'

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> select * where {
?film  rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>
?film dbpprop:title ?acteurs
}
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define prefix first. And also you forget . in your query.

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpprop:<http://dbpedia.org/property/> 

select * where {
 ?film  rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>.
 ?film dbpprop:title ?acteurs
}
```